# What can I use instead of CASE WHEN THEN in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have an INSERT SELECT query with CASE WHEN THEN, but it seems to be a problem to run it.
I receive:

> Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query
> Error Code: 1205. Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

What can I use instead of CASE WHEN THEN?

I need to insert ids in the columns `degree_type_id`, `marital_status_id`, `employment_field_id`.
I'm selecting from tables:

- new_coders_survey_data,
- dw_time_dim

Is there other way to insert id numbers in my FACT table (`dw_coder_fact`) into that 3 columns?

I have tables:

- `dw_marital_status_dim`
- `dw_education_dim`
- `dw_employment_field_dim`
  They have 2 columns: 1) id, 2) description

Kind regards,
Anna

```
INSERT INTO dw_coder_fact 
        (age, 
         gender, 
         country_citizen, 
         country_live, 
         city_population, 
         is_ethnic_minority, 
         language_at_home, 
         degree_type_id, 
         school_major, 
         marital_status_id, 
         has_children, 
         children_number, 
         employment_status, 
         employment_field_id, 
         is_software_dev, 
         months_programming, 
         is_underemployed, 
         income, 
         survey_date, 
         date_id, 
         attended_bootcamp, 
         bootcamp_fulljob_after, 
         bootcamp_postsalary, 
         hours_learning, 
         bootcamploanyesno, 
         money_for_learning, 
         has_student_debt, 
         student_debt_owe, 
         has_debt, 
         has_home_mortgage, 
         home_mortgage_owe, 
         financially_supporting, 
         has_financially_dependents, 
         job_apply_when, 
         type_of_company_pref, 
         job_role_interest, 
         job_where_pref, 
         expected_earning) 
SELECT s.age, 
       s.gender, 
       s.countrycitizen, 
       s.countrylive, 
       s.citypopulation, 
       s.isethnicminority, 
       s.languageathome, 
       CASE s.schooldegree 
         WHEN "associate's degree" THEN 1 
         WHEN "bachelor's degree" THEN 2 
         WHEN 'high school diploma or equivalent (GED)' THEN 3 
         WHEN "master's degree (non-professional)" THEN 4 
         WHEN 'no high school (secondary school)' THEN 5 
         WHEN 'Ph.D.' THEN 6 
         WHEN 'professional degree (MBA, MD, JD, etc.)' THEN 7 
         WHEN 'some college credit, no degree' THEN 8 
         WHEN 'some high school' THEN 9 
         WHEN 'trade, technical. or vocational training' THEN 10 
         ELSE 11 
       end AS DegreeTypeDescription, 
       s.schoolmajor, 
       CASE s.maritalstatus 
         WHEN 'divorced' THEN 1 
         WHEN 'married or domestic partnership' THEN 2 
         WHEN 'separated' THEN 3 
         WHEN 'single, never married' THEN 4 
         WHEN 'widowed' THEN 5 
         ELSE 6 
       end AS MaritalStatusDescription, 
       s.haschildren, 
       s.childrennumber, 
       s.employmentstatus, 
       CASE s.employmentfield 
         WHEN 'architecture or physical engineering' THEN 1 
         WHEN 'arts, entertainmant, sports, or media' THEN 2 
         WHEN 'constraction and extraction' THEN 3 
         WHEN 'education' THEN 4 
         WHEN 'farming, fishing, and forestry' THEN 5 
         WHEN 'finance' THEN 6 
         WHEN 'food and beverage' THEN 7 
         WHEN 'health care' THEN 8 
         WHEN 'law enforcement and fire and rescue' THEN 9 
         WHEN 'legal' THEN 10 
         WHEN 'office and administrative support' THEN 11 
         WHEN 'sales' THEN 12 
         WHEN 'software development' THEN 13 
         WHEN 'software development and IT' THEN 14 
         WHEN 'transportation' THEN 15 
         ELSE 16 
       end AS EmploymentFieldDescription, 
       s.issoftwaredev, 
       s.monthsprogramming, 
       s.isunderemployed, 
       s.income, 
       s.part1starttime, 
       t.date_id, 
       s.attendedbootcamp, 
       s.bootcampfulljobafter, 
       s.bootcamppostsalary, 
       s.hourslearning, 
       s.bootcamploanyesno, 
       s.moneyforlearning, 
       s.hasstudentdebt, 
       s.studentdebtowe, 
       s.hasdebt, 
       s.hashomemortgage, 
       s.homemortgageowe, 
       s.financiallysupporting, 
       s.hasfinancialdependents, 
       s.jobapplywhen, 
       s.jobpref, 
       s.jobroleinterest, 
       s.jobwherepref, 
       s.expectedearning 
FROM   new_coders_survey_data s, 
       dw_time_dim t;
```

Comment: You have a comma join with no where condition - did you intend to insert a cartesian product? and out of interest how many records are there in new_coders_survey_data and
       dw_time_dim?

Comment: P.Salmon, what is comma join? I have empty table and trying to insert into it values from 2 other tables. It is 33 787 records in new_coders_survey_data and 33 787 records in dw_time_dim. I don't know what is cartesian product..

Comment: Then you need to do a bit of research - a comma join will generate 37787 * 37787 rows which is a lot (1427857369) 'INNER JOIN and , (comma) are semantically equivalent in the absence of a join condition: both produce a Cartesian product between the specified tables (that is, each and every row in the first table is joined to each and every row in the second table).' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html your comma join is FROM   new_coders_survey_data s, 
       dw_time_dim t;

Comment: @Anna Why do you have two tables in the `FROM` clause? Do you want to combine all rows from the first table against all rows from the second table? Probably not; there should be a join predicate there.

Comment: Oh, thank you, I understand it now.  added                                                             
       WHERE s.Part1StartTime = t.survey_date_time limit 1;                                                            I tried inserting 1 record, works perfectly. But 5 rows give an ERROR Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query. I increased "DBMS connection read timeout interval" and "innodb_lock_wait_timeout". Waiting for an INSERT. Many thanks!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: P.Salmon. It took  171.813 sec and returned with the message
'''34323 row(s) affected Records: 34323  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0'''. Somehow there are more then 33 787 records now

Comment: The Impaler, thank you, I've added WHERE condition now. But end up with more rows. Instead of 33 787, it is inserted 34 323 rows...

Comment: Ok, I see, this is because that column has not only unique values. So I changed it to inner join: '''''''FROM New_Coders_Survey_Data s
 INNER JOIN dw_time_dim t ON s.Part1StartTime = t.survey_date_time;'''''' But it is still returns with the message:  ''''''34323 row(s) affected Records: 34323 Duplicates: 0 Warnings: 0''''''

Comment: I suggest you cut down the number of rows until you get the logic and outcomes right - even 10 rows should do. BTW if you want to attract someones attention you should prefix their name with the at symbol ('@')

Comment: @P.Salmon, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

@P.Salmon comments are pertinent. What is the relation between your [new_coder_survey_data] and your [dw_time_dim] table? It looks that the dw_time_dim records when a survey has been made to get data that is placed in the new_coder_survey_data. If this is correct there should be a way to identify the subject of the survey on both tables, usually and id field even though we can assume that using the full name, among other alternatives, it's also possible.
If my assumptions are correct you just need to set an inner join between both tables as:

```
FROM   new_coders_survey_data s
       INNER JOIN dw_time_dim t
       ON s.id = t.personid
```

or if you have to refer to a fullname

```
FROM   new_coders_survey_data s
           INNER JOIN dw_time_dim t
           ON s.fullname = t.personname
```

I do not find any field in your dw_coder_fact table that allow to identify the person in question (no id, no name, no address).
Anyway, the coma join you have will demand a long processing time and a terrible effort to evaluate it.

Comment: thank you. I have common column survey_date_time to join on. The coder_id column is not here as it is AUTO_INCREMENT. Many thanks!